# Copyright text on Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, overlay, copyright-display

Is there a way to affect the styling of the copyright part in google maps API v3?
I'd like to move it up by 10 pixels for example, since I have some overlapping right now and it doesn't show up (and that's contrary to the Terms of service).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have never come across away, and i very much doubt there is, google dont own copyright to all there maps and would probably have legal agreements with other map providers.

It just would not be worth it for them.

Out of interest what are you trying to put there?

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch your reply. I have a PNG overlay over that part (fade in effect) so I'm afraid if I cover the copyright I'm violating the terms. Hence, I wanted to position the copyright differently (top: -20px for example).

Comment: as the copyright is not only googles, you might find it cant be moved because that would be in beach of there agreement with the original copyright holder... although whatever the reason its not possible as far as i can tell.